# компилирование python в exe

Tags: python, exe

Добрый день, написал небольшое приложение в python (с использованием pygmae), пытаюсь скомпилировать в ехе с помощью cx_Freeze, не получается. 
Подскажите пожалуйста какой то еще компилятор или где можно подсмотреть решение ?

Comment: Имеет смысл разобраться почему не получается. Я пробовал cx_Freeze, py2exe, PyInstaller, Nuitka - везде есть свои нюансы, но в принципе получалось. По поводу "где можно подсмотреть решение" - нужно прямо в вопросе описать что не получалось.

Comment: *"не получается"* не слишком информативно. Какие конкретно шаги выполняли? Что ожидали получить? Что вместо этого происходит? Работают ли для вас простые ("hello world") примеры? Какой минимальный код воспроизводит вашу ошибку? Какая операционная система, версия Питона, используемых библиотек итд.

Answer (score 1):

Я PyInstaller'ом пользовался. Довольно простой и удобный вариант.
`http://www.pyinstaller.org/`